# What are the available tools to summarize or simplify text?

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

Is there any library, preferably in python but at least open source, that can summarize and or simplify natural-language text?

Comment: There is another library which is based on the 'TextRank' algorithm which you can find here. https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim

Comment: There is hardly any program which can do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is currently any libraries that do this, as text summarization, or at least **understandable** text summarization isn't something that will be easily accomplished by a simple plug & play library.

Here are a few links that I managed to find regarding projects / resources that are related to text summarization to get you started:

- [The Lemur Project](http://www.lemurproject.org/)
- [Python Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/)
- [O'Reilly's Book on Natural Language Processing in Python](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516499)
- [Google Resource on Natural Language Processing](https://web.archive.org/web/20140821083738/http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/book.html)
- [Tutorial : How to create a keyword summary of text in Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20140215021123/http://www.mindtwist.de/main/linux/3-linux-tipps/37-how-to-create-a-keyword-summary-of-a-text-with-python.html)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Some dead links in the answer, replaced with cached pages from https://archive.org/web/

Answer (score 27):

Maybe you can try [sumy](https://github.com/miso-belica/sumy). It's a quite small library that I wrote in Python. There are implemented Luhn's and Edmundson's approaches, LSA method, SumBasic, KL-Sum, LexRank and TextRank algorithms. It's Apache2 licensed and supports Czech, Slovak, English, French, Japanese, Chinese, Portuguese, Spanish and German languages.

Feel free to open an issue or send a pull request if there is something you are missing.

Comment: I love Sumy. Its very easy to use. What is your prefered method? Isn't `LSA` the most recent natural language methodology and theoretically the best one compared to the other options?

Comment: Hi, thanks. As with almost everything there is no silver bullet, but LSA is the most advanced method in sumy.

Comment: I've done a ton of testing with sumy on wikipedia articles and peer-reviewed articles, and I personally get by far the best results with KL, but it also takes about 200 times longer than any of the other summarizers.

Comment: @Xodarap777 can you write what other summarizers did you try? And maybe even link to your code with experiments?

Comment: @Xodarap777 can you please share what type of measurement you used to compare the produced summaries?

Answer (score 4):

I needed also the same thing but I couldn't find anything in **Python** that helped me have a **Comprehensive** Result.

So I found this Web Service really useful, and they have a free [API](http://smmry.com/api) which gives a JSON result, and I wanted to share it with you.

Check it out here: http://smmry.com

Answer (score 3):

Try [Open Text Summarizer](http://libots.sourceforge.net/) which is released under the GPL open source license.  It works reasonably well but there has been no development work on it since 2007.

The original code is written in C (both a library and a command line utility) but there are wrappers to it in a number of languages:

- [Perl](http://www.splitbrain.org/services/ots)
- [Ruby](http://intridea.com/2010/12/3/summarize-a-ruby-c-binding-for-open-text-summarizer)
- [Python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ots/0.4.2.1)
- [C#](http://ots.codeplex.com)

Comment: C# http://ots.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Not python but [MEAD](http://www.summarization.com/mead/) will do text summarization (it's in Perl).  Usually what comes out is comprehensible, if not always particularly fluent sounding.  Also check out [summarization.com](http://www.summarization.com/) for a lot of good information on the text summarization task.

Comment: the link for summarization.com is dead. Kindly replace it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [article](https://rare-technologies.com/text-summarization-in-python-extractive-vs-abstractive-techniques-revisited/) which does a detailed study of these methods and packages:

1. Lex_rank ([sumy](https://github.com/miso-belica/sumy))
2. LSA (sumy)
3. Luhn (sumy)
4. [PyTeaser](https://github.com/xiaoxu193/PyTeaser)
5. [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/lsimodel.html) TextRank
6. [PyTextRank](https://github.com/ceteri/pytextrank)
7. Google [TextSum](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/textsum)

The ending of the article does a '[summary](https://rare-technologies.com/text-summarization-in-python-extractive-vs-abstractive-techniques-revisited/#to_summarize)'.

The author of sumy @[miso.belica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988107/miso-belica) has given a description in an answer above.

Various other ML techniques have risen, such as [Facebook/NAMAS](https://github.com/facebookarchive/NAMAS) and Google/TextSum but still need extensive training in Gigaword Dataset and about 7000 GPU hours. The dataset itself is quite costly.

In conclusion I would say sumy is the best option in the market right now if you don't have access to high-end machines. Thanks a lot @miso.belica for this wonderful package.

Answer (score 1):

A while back, I wrote a summarization library for python using NLTK, using an algorithm from the Classifier4J library. It's pretty simple but it may suit the needs of anyone that needs summarization: https://github.com/thavelick/summarize