# Auto Text Summarization

Tags: python, django, nlp, summarization

I have decided to develop a **Auto Text Summarization** Tool using Python/Django.

Can someone please recommend books or articles on how to get started?

Is there any open source algorithm or made project in the **Auto Text Summarization** so that I can gain the idea?

Also, would you like to suggest me the new challenging FYP for me in Django/Python?

Comment: This idea is already done. What you are looking for is `Summly` app They even release some API things, hope that helps you.

Comment: You got to do yourself. may be this is not the right way to ask ideas.

Comment: Before you decided on what you were going to develop, you didn't research it?

Comment: This question is perhaps not a very good fit for Stackoverflow, but regarding @Surya's comment: The fact that an application exists hardly justifies not trying to create a better one. Also, summly is _one_ iPhone app that uses natural language summarization techniques, but the the idea is much much older than that, and there is a whole branch of NLP research dedicated to it.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479333/summarize-text-or-simplify-text

Answer (score 2):

First off for Paper, I recommend:

1- Recent automatic text summarization techniques: a survey by M.Gambhir and V.Gupta
2- A Survey of Text Summarization Techniques, A.Nenkova

As for tools for Python, I suggest taking a look at these tools:

1. The Conqueror: NLTK
2. The Prince: TextBlob
3. The Mercenary: Stanford CoreNLP
4. The Usurper: spaCy
5. The Admiral: gensim
   First off learn about different kinds of summarizations and what suits you best. Also, remember to make sure you have a proper preprocessing tool for the language you are targeting as this is very important for the quality of your summarizer.

Answer (score 0):

About papers, I would like to add to the previous answer next ones:

1. "Text Data Management and Analysis" by ChengXiang Zhai and Sean Massung, chapter 16.
2. "Texts in Computer Science: Fundamentals of Predictive Text Mining" by Sholom M. Weiss, 
   Nitin Indurkhya and Tong Zhang (second edition), chapter 9.