# Open source Summly (language summarizing)

Tags: nlp

Is there an open source library that duplicates the features of Summly, namely summarizing large articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the Open Text Summarizer, downloadable at [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libots/). For more ideas, please see the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479333/summarize-text-or-simplify-text) question.