# where to get News summarization corpus?

Tags: nlp, text-mining

Is there any publicly available news+summary corpus for automatic summarization. If yes, can you please provide way to get it ?

Comment: When you say "publicly available" do you consider paid corpora? The Summbank 1.0 here: http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/catalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC2003T16 is available for a fee.

Comment: @Yasen , Is there any corpus available at free of cost ?

Comment: Does it help? http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~swan/summarization/projects_full.htm

Comment: I am also looking for a similar corpus free of charge for evaluation purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can also get Priberam Compressive Summarization Corpus for free, it's in Portuguese:

http://labs.priberam.com/Resources/PCSC.aspx

> This corpus contains 801 documents split into 80 topics, each of which has 10 documents (one has 11). The documents are news stories from major Portuguese newspapers, radio and TV stations. Each topic also has two human generated summaries up to 100 words. The human summaries are compressive: the annotators performed only sentence and word deletion operations.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Open Text Summarizer, downloadable at [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libots/). For more ideas, please see the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479333/summarize-text-or-simplify-text) question.