# How do I get only a determined number of words from a string using regex?

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a long string from which a short description has to be generated. To generate short description I have to take 75 words from long string.How this can be done using regex ?

Comment: Please paste the code you tried and we'll help on that.

Comment: It seems that you need [`text summarization`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479333/summarize-text-or-simplify-text) not a regex

Comment: There is no regex support in XSLT 1.0, so your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
(?:\w+\W*){1,75}
```

Details:

- a non-empty sequence of "word" chars,
- an optional sequence of "non-word" chars (optional to catch also the case
  when the input has exactly 75 words, without any non-word char after it),
- within a non-capturing group (otherwise the 1st capturing group would
  have contained the last word),
- repeated from 1 to 75 Times.

The *full match* catches all the text.

Do not use the *global* switch, as you want catch only the **first**
set of 75 words.